# Passing list of objects from controller to View in MVC4

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP/MVC and as part of that started learning using a simple app.

I have a collection of objects as below in the controller

```
    public ActionResult loadimage(String FQDN, String trange)
        {
            List<geo_crd> Geo_crd = new List<geo_crd>();

              //more logic


foreach (ToDoItem T in query1)
            {

                IEnumerable<GeoItem> query2 = (from b in db1.GeoItems
                                               where b.DNS_server_address == T.DNS_server_address
                                               select b);
                foreach (GeoItem X in query2)
                {

                    Geo_crd.Add(new geo_crd(X.DNS_latitude, X.DNS_longitude, 1));
                }

            }


            return View(Geo_crd);
        }
```

Geo_crd is in models as follows

```
namespace ToDoApp.Models
{
        public class geo_crd 
    {

        private Decimal _geo_lat;
        private Decimal _geo_long;
        private int _status_flag;

        public geo_crd(Decimal x, Decimal y, int z)
        {
            _geo_lat = x;
            _geo_long = y;
            _status_flag = z;
        }

        public Decimal geo_lat
        {
            get { return _geo_lat; }
            set { _geo_lat = value; }
        }

        public Decimal geo_long
        {
            get { return _geo_long; }
            set { _geo_long = value; }
        }

        public int status_flag
        {
            get { return _status_flag; }
            set { _status_flag = value; }
        }


    }
}
```

I am receiving in the views as follows

```
@model IEnumerable <ToDoApp.Models.geo_crd>
// more code here 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    @foreach (var item in Model){ 
            <spam><li> @item.geo_lat </li></spam>
            <span> <li> AddLocationPin(@item.geo_lat, @item.geo_long, null, 'place 1');</li> </span> 
           } 

  </script>
```

the issue I am having is , the server is not sending the AddlocatioPin , it is just ignoring it I guess.

am i doing something really stupid ?
please help

Answer (score 1):

You should not wrap html tags with `script`. 
Start and end tags, also their order must match in html. Also you should read more about [HTML ul tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp)

Correct view would be

```
@model IEnumerable <ToDoApp.Models.geo_crd>
//more code here 
<ul>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   { 
       <li><span>@item.geo_lat </span></li>
       <li><span>AddLocationPin(@item.geo_lat, @item.geo_long, null, 'place 1'); </span> </li>
   } 
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @archil, but for some reason it is still not passing the AddLocationPin when the client view is created and sent. Am i missing something too basic here ?

Comment: that issue was  html tags within script. Otherwise the solution worked. so accepting it as an answer. what worked is as below